# What is a thread pool in C++ and how it is implemented?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I just came across a new term: `thread pool`. I don't know what it is, can any ody offer some information about this?

What it is a thread pool and how it is implemented?

Is a thread pool just a collection of threads?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern

Answer (score 4):

ThreadPool is basically collection of threads. Whenever a task is assigned to the threadpool, the available thread accepts the task and executes it.

The advantages of thread pool is to control the threads creation\destruction and also, optimize the thread usage.

Thread Pool concept  is not the C++ language feature. There are many custom implementation of thread Pool. ( Using different strategies).

You can also read

- [thread pool in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973903.aspx)
- [The threadpool library](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/)

to know
   more.